# What is wrong with my SFINAE to check for std::map/std::vector?

Tags: c++, sfinae, std

I have a simple SFINAE scenario to distinuish standard containers like `std::map`:

```
 template <typename Container> struct HasKeyType : sfinae_test { // (C)
   template <typename U> static Yes test(typename Container::key_type*); // (A)
   template <typename U> static No test(...);
   enum {value = (sizeof(test(null)) == sizeof(Yes))}; // (B)
 };
```

With

```
 struct sfinae_test {
   typedef char Yes;
   typedef long No;
   static void* const null;
 };
```

When I instantiate this with `HasKeyType<std::vector<int> >::value`, I get

```
(A) error: no type named ‘key_type’ in ‘class std::vector<int>’
(B) error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct HasKeyType<std::vector<int> >’
(C) error: declaration of ‘struct HasKeyType<std::vector<int> >’
```

I'm completely stumped at this. Why is `HasKeyType` incomplete, and why doesn't SFINAE work?

I get similar errors to `(B)` and `(C)` as well if I instantiate `HasKeyType<std::map<int,float> >` which in fact *has* a key type (`int`).

g++ version: 4.5.2 (yes, I know it's old)

Comment: 4.5's not old! I have to use 2.95 every day (for our SPARC Sol-8 customers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the template `U` in your `test` method:

```
template <typename Container> struct HasKeyType : sfinae_test { // C
  template <typename U> static Yes test(typename U::key_type* ); // A
  template <typename U> static No test(U*);
  enum {value = (sizeof(test<Container>(0)) == sizeof(Yes))}; // B
};
```

Note that I changed the `test(null)` for a `test<Container>(0)`. If your compiler supports it(well, gcc 4.5 doesn't...), you could use `nullptr` instead of `0`.

Comment: Oh boy, I must be blind. I've been looking at this for an hour or more. Thanks!